# How to have win32com code completion in IPython?

Tags: python, autocomplete, ipython, win32com

Via

```
import win32com.client
wordapp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
```

I can get a Word `Application` object documented e.g. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515.aspx). However, `ipython`'s autocompletion is not aware of that API, is there any way to add that?

Comment: You will have to use the documentation or a COM browser to get familiar  with the API. The python object is only Proxy object, if you `dir` it it will only show the `__special__` methods. In your case there is good documentation available, so it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @Dabrion Although that throws the more general question whether there is a way to automagically link a well-formatted documentation to `dir`... I'll have to think about this some more

Comment: I dont think so, it seems infeasible to try all possible methods names. So this responsibility lies with the com object, which should provide a method list when you get the handle. I remember this functionality (com browser?). It has been some time that worked with Windows stuff.. so I am afraid have to refer you to the docs for details.

Comment: @Dabrion Oh no, brute force would be a bad idea. I meant, some smart logic that uses e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb244515.aspx to obtain the actually available names. I know little of COM, so the browser you mentioned is something I have to read up on first...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Quick solution

Perhaps the simplest way to achieve code completion in IPython (tested with 6.2.1, see [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56094531/5085211) for a snippet that works with 7.1) and Jupyter is to run the following snippet:

```
from IPython.utils.generics import complete_object
import win32com.client

@complete_object.when_type(win32com.client.DispatchBaseClass)
def complete_dispatch_base_class(obj, prev_completions):
    try:
        ole_props = set(obj._prop_map_get_).union(set(obj._prop_map_put_))
        return list(ole_props) + prev_completions
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

[image]

[image]

## Short story long

With some more details being outlined in [this guide](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/QuickStartClientCom.html), `win32com` ships with a script, `makepy.py` for generating Python types corresponding to the type library of a given COM object.

In the case of Word 2016, we would proceed as follows:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\pkgs\pywin32-221-py36h9c10281_0\Lib\site-packages\win32com\client>python makepy.py -i "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library"

Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library
 {00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}, lcid=0, major=8, minor=7
 >>> # Use these commands in Python code to auto generate .py support
 >>> from win32com.client import gencache
 >>> gencache.EnsureModule('{00020905-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', 0, 8, 7)
```

The location of `makepy.py` will of course depend on your Python distribution. The script `combrowse.py`, available in the same directory, can be used to find the names of available type libraries.

With that in place, `win32com.client` will automatically make use of the generated types, rather than the raw `IPyDispatch`, and at this point, auto-completion is available in e.g. IPython or Jupyter, given that the COM object of interest actually publishes its available properties and methods (which is not a requirement).

Now, in your case, by invoking `EnsureDispatch` instead of `Dispatch`, the `makepy` part of the process is performed automatically, so you really should be able to obtain code completion in IPython for the published methods:

[image]

Note, though, that while this does give code completion for methods, the same will not be true for properties. It is possible to inspect those using the `_prop_map_get_` attribute. For example, `wordapp.Selection.Range.Font._prop_map_get_` gives all properties available on fonts.

If using IPython is not a strong requirement, note also that the PythonWin shell (located around `\pkgs\pywin32\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe`) has built-in code completion support for both properties and methods.

[image]

This, by itself, suggests that the same is achievable in IPython.

Concretely, the logic for auto-completion, which in turn relies on `_prop_map_get_`, can be found in `scintilla.view.CScintillaView._AutoComplete`. On the other hand, code completion in IPython 6.2.1 is handled by `core.completer.IPCompleter`. The API for adding custom code completers is provided by [`IPython.utils.generics.complete_object`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/fc7d8a365a33f0de01b1b19b8a2a8ecd42f61f83/IPython/utils/generics.py#L18), as illustrated in the first solution above. One gotcha is that with `complete_object` being based on [`simplegeneric`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplegeneric), only one completer may be provided for any given type. Luckily, all types generated by `makepy` will inherit from `win32com.client.DispatchBaseClass`.

If this turns out to ever be an issue, one can also circumvent `complete_object` entirely and simply manually patch IPython by adding the following five lines to `core.completer.Completion.attr_matches`:

```
try:
    ole_props = set(obj._prop_map_get_).union(set(obj._prop_map_put_))
    words += list(ole_props)
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

Conversely, IPython [bases its code-completion on `__dir__`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/config/integrating.html#tab-completion), so one could also patch [`gencache`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/master/com/win32com/client/gencache.py), which is where the code generation ultimately happens, to include something to like

```
def __dir__(self):
    return list(set(self._prop_map_get_).union(set(self._prop_map_put_)))
```

to each generated `DispatchBaseClass`.

Answer (score 5):

[fuglede's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47613008/2455980) is great, just want to update it for the newest versions of IPython (7.1+).
Since [`IPython.utils.generics`](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/utils/generics.py) has changes from using [`simplegeneric`](https://pypi.org/project/simplegeneric/) to using [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch), the `@complete_object.when_type` method should be changed to `@complete_object.register`. So his initial code should changed to:

```
from IPython.utils.generics import complete_object
import win32com.client

@complete_object.register(win32com.client.DispatchBaseClass)
def complete_dispatch_base_class(obj, prev_completions):
    try:
        ole_props = set(obj._prop_map_get_).union(set(obj._prop_map_put_))
        return list(ole_props) + prev_completions
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

Comment: I tried it in Spyder's IPython console and it executes the code without error, but I get no code completion. I tried to enable greedy or jedi code completion, but no change. Do I miss something?