# How to have a Static Dispatch object behave more Dynamic?

Tags: python, win32com, dispatch

Let's say I use

```
app = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch("InDesign.Application")
```

to obtain an InDesign Application object. Now I can use

```
mainmenu = app.menus["$ID/Main"]
```

to access InDesign's main menu, but unfortunately end up with only `<COM object <unknown>>` for everything. If I use

```
app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("InDesign.Application")
```

instead, I get a more meaningful `<win32com.gen_py.Adobe InDesign CC 2015 TypeLibrary._Application instance at 0x....>` and `dir(app)` lists some properties (*excluding* `menus`) but now I need to use both uppercase `app.Menus` and cannot use Pythonic item indexing but have to resort to the awful

```
mainmenu = app.Menus.Items("$ID/Main")
```

instead. Is there any way to get the best of both worlds?

**edit** I [have the respective `.tlb`-file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42273433/321973), does that help somehow? Or would I really have to write a wrapper (or delegator?) for each COM object I'd like to use? Isn't that the same what `win32com.client.makepy` seems to do?

Comment: slightly related (and also by me): [How to have win32com-autocompletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26990655/321973)