# How to get code-completion for COM programming in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, win32com, code-completion, typelib

When using `app = win32com.client.Dispatch('Some.Application')`, is there any feasible way get code-completion in PyCharm? It is rather tedious having to retype (or copy-paste) everything from an API documentation, so would creating [skeletons](https://github.com/JetBrains/python-skeletons) be. Is there no other way to let PyCharm know about the Interface provided via COM, especially if I can provide a `.tlb` file? Or is there at least some way automatically generate such a skeleton (or a wrapping module?) from the TypeLib?

Comment: Strongly related: [How to have win32com-autocompletion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26990655/321973) - I notice I tend to ask similar questions again after some years...The other question does however ask about [tag:ipython] and `EnsureDispatch`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since there is no way for PyCharm to know the runtime type of `app`, you shouldn't expect to get code completion on `app` directly; at least not until they decide to add built-in support for generating code from type libraries.

However, you can exploit the fact that `win32com` implicitly generates code based on the type library as described in [the first part of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47613008/5085211), together with PyCharm's support for type hinting, to get code completion on COM methods.

1. Make sure that the Python types have been generated; their location is determined by the GUID of the COM object. For example, the types for Microsoft Word 2016 on my machine are available in
   `C:\Users\username\appdata\local\temp\gen_py\3.6\00020905-0000-0000-c000-000000000046x0x8x7\`.
2. Add this folder to the path of your PyCharm Python interpreter; see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885821/how-do-i-import-modules-in-pycharm#19885882).
3. Import the modules for which you want code completion.

In the screenshots below, we use this approach with Word's [`Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.find(v=office.14).aspx):

[image]

[image]

Now, besides feeling dirty, this approach relies on the relevant types having been generated and the code completion is limited to the methods published by the object, so I imagine its usefulness in practice might be somewhat limited; in particular, anybody working on the code will have to generate the code, or the annotations will cause `NameError`s. Personally, I would probably prefer using Jupyter for the exploratory part of the implementation process, and with minimal tweaks outlined in [the answer mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47613008/5085211), Jupyter can be extended to have full code completion with `win32com`.